# MongoDB - Limit number of records in related model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have just started learning Node and MongoDB and I'm building an application for my wedding to try out these technologies.

Part of the application will focus on the assignment of guests to tables for the wedding breakfast. So far I have a Guest schema like so:

```
const guestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  attending: String,
  allergies: String,
  menu: String
});

const tableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  capacity: Number,
  **guests: [
      { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Guest' }
  ]**
```

I am aware that I can create a relationship between guests and tables as shown in bold but I'd like to limit the number of 'related' guests to a table according to the capacity of the table. E.g - tableOne might have 5 people, tableTwo might have 7, etc. I know that I could do this in Node by using my capacity field and performing a query before I relate a guest to a table, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this on the database side as I'd imagine this would be better practice?

All thoughts welcome,

Thanks

Comment: Not as a separate collection. If it was all actually "embedded" in the array then it's manageable in even **one** update request. But until transactions become a thing, you can't really do that without feedback from either the parent property as you suggest, or from within the array of id values.

Comment: So with that in mind, If these are "tables" as in a restaurant, then ***surely*** it's not possible for a "guest" to sit at more than one table at a time ( quantum mechanics aside ). Therefore you really **"should"** be embedding the data instead. And this would solve the problem.

Comment: So do you mean create the relationship the other way around and have tables assigned to guests? That would work coz you could just have a single table id for each guest. Apologies for the newbie question, historically this kinda stuff has always been done by back-end dev colleagues. Full stack JS has opened up this world to front enders like myself!

Comment: Nope I mean "embed the guests in the table".You know `guests: [guestSchema]`. There's no point in having the other collection, or at the very least it suits your purposes far better to simply "embed" at least the detail you need in the array of the table object. In that way and update can actually query the array size before adding anything. Or the counter for that matter.